# Some NLog logs aren't saved to azure table storage

Tags: c#, .net, azure, logging, nlog

I use NLog and Azure diagnostics for logging .Bellow you can see my setting in config file related to logging

```xml
<system.diagnostics>
 <trace>
  <listeners>
    <add type="Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Diagnostics.DiagnosticMonitorTraceListener, Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Diagnostics, Version=2.8.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken="adfsdasfzxc" name="AzureDiagnostics">
      <filter type="" />
    </add>
  </listeners>
 </trace>
</system.diagnostics>
<nlog>
 <targets>
  <target type="Mail"
        name="email"
        html="True"
        addNewLines="True"
        layout="${longdate} ${uppercase:${level}} ${message} ${exception:format=tostring}"
        subject="Log"
        to="someemail@com"
        from="someemail@com"
        smtpUserName="smtpUserName"
        enableSsl="True"
        smtpPassword="smtpPassword"
        smtpAuthentication="Basic"
        smtpServer="smtp.sendgrid.net"
        smtpPort="587" />
</targets>
<rules>
  <logger name="*" minlevel="Trace" writeTo="trace" />
  <logger name="MyClassName" minlevel="Error" writeTo="email" />
</rules>
```

How you can see ,I want to send error logs from my class 'MyClassName' to email and other logs I want to save in table storage. Sometimes everything is OK, I get email about error and than I can find log about the error in table storage WADLogsTable. But sometimes I get **only** email . For some reason sometimes log records aren't saved in table storage. How can I understand what is wrong?

Comment: You can add a target="file" and look at this file if it contains log. The problem in azure configuration.

Comment: `<logger name="*" minlevel="Trace" writeTo="trace" />` I don't think that works. There is not target "trace"? Are you trying to write nlog stuff to DiagnosticMonitorTraceListener or otherwise around ?

Comment: @Julian,you are right.It wtites to DiagnosticMonitorTraceListener

Comment: @Mehmet,I've already tried adding target="file",and yes,this file contains all logs

Comment: Could you share us the definition of your class 'MyClassName'? You could show us the code of the methods you define to trace logs.